# Angular 2 nested injection

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular-providers

I am struggling with angular2's dependency injection. In my example I have two Services.

- Service1 injects Service2 and gets data from it.
- A Component injects Service1 and fetches the data from Service1

I have to provide Service2 in my Component

```
@Component({
  providers: [Service1, Service2]
})
```

**But why? I injected Service2 in Service1. Why do I have to provide Service2 in my Component, when there's no reference to Service2 in my Component?**

I am aware, that I could provide services in my bootsrap function, but I would like to provide my Services to my Component...

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [... Service1, Service2])
```

Here is my example code, which is not working because of the missing provider

**component.ts**

```
import {Service1} from "service1.ts";    

@Component({
  providers: [Service1]
})
export class Component{
  constructor(private s: Service1) {
    //get data from Service1
  }
}
```

**service1.ts**

```
import {Service2} from "service2.ts";

@Injectable()
export class service1{
  constructor(private s2: Service2) {
    //get data from service2
    //edit data
    //return data
  }
}
```

**service2.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class service2{
  constructor() {
    //return data
  }
}
```

Comment: In theory, what you're doing is right. What error message are you getting?

Comment: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Service2!

Comment: OH My bad, I thought you were providing both services in the bootstrap. @smyk answer is right. DI is dependent on component tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular needs to know, where to find the services. That's what providers array (either in the component or in the bootstrap call) is used for. You can think of it as of a hierarchical registry. If you want the services to be injected, you need to feed them to the registry.

In Angular1 the services were registered in the registry by calling the `factory` function or alike. Here the logic is different.

All in all, even if the component is not directly bound to the service, it has to register it, so that Angular becomes aware it exists.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up. So there is not way to "hide" Service2? This means, that i always have to provide and import all services which are used in my Service1, right? Seems a bit inconvenient to me...

Comment: Correct. You have to explicitly specify Service2 as a provider somewhere in your app.